# Sci-Fi site doesn't say "And Fantasy" in very many places in the SEN

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, fantasy

In many places on the Stack Exchange Network, there is no mention of the Fantasy side of the Sci-Fi site.

For instance here on Meta when you ask a question:

[image: Lack of Fantasy on Meta]

On the little stack exchange widget:

[image: No fantasy on SEN widget]

On Area 51:

[image: No Fantasy on Area51]

On http://stackexchange.com/:

[image: Stack Exchange lacks fantasy]

There are a few other examples, but you get the point.

Is there anyway that we can get the title changed on these sites to include Fantasy?

How can we attract Fantasy fans from the SEN if they know not of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have updated the sites table to include "and Fantasy".

Area 51 is also updated now.

Comment: I know your not supposed to say thanks, and instead simply upvote someone.  But thanks!

Comment: You did change the title, but not the description. It's still described as "Q&A for science fiction enthusiasts", omitting fantasy.

Comment: Also Area51 hasn't changed but that could be caching.